# system status page missing after upgrade

Tags: system-status

Upgraded civicrm from 5.63.2 to 5.66.2. Upgrade finished ok and everything was working ok apart from the system status page being blank. Running on wordpress 6.4.2 and php 7.4.3.

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console when viewing the status page?

Answer (score 0):

I'd started from  the "Settings - Cleanup Caches and Update Paths", accompanied by  civicrm / cms / webserver / browser dev console logs inspection

Comment: Thank you. I had to restore the system but I will try these suggestions when I next try the upgrade

Comment: I tried "Settings - Cleanup Caches and Update Paths", accompanied by civicrm / cms / webserver / browser dev console logs inspection but nothing has changed

Comment: I missed the info in the javascript console, the message is Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
https://civi.cotswoldcanals.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fajax%2Frest"  and further info is "Ajax requests can only be issued by javascript clients, eg. CRM.api3()."}"